# mysql error code 1022 duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I searched through the prior posts but didn't quite find the answer, so here it goes ...

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `leags` 
(
   `lid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `lName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `links` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `cid` int(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`lid`),
   KEY `index2` (`lid`,`lName`),
   KEY `index3` (`lid`,`lName`,`cid`),
   KEY `cid_idx` (`cid`),
   CONSTRAINT `cid` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `cats` (`cid`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Leagues'$$
```

I have another table that has the above PK as a foreign key.

```
CREATE  TABLE `tams` 
(
  `tId` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `tName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `lid` INT(10) NULL ,
  `url` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tId`) ,
  INDEX `index2` (`tId` ASC, `tName` ASC) ,
  INDEX `index3` (`tId` ASC, `tName` ASC, `lid` ASC) ,
  INDEX `lid_idx` (`lid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `lid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`lid` )
    REFERENCES leags` (`lid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The creation of this table works fine, but I run into a problem creating the below table.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spSched 
(
  `spscId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `startDate` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `endDate` DATE NULL ,
  `startTime` TIME NOT NULL ,
  `endTime` TIME NULL ,
  `htId` INT(10) NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `atId` INT(10) NULL ,
  `leagId` INT(10) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`spscId`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `spscId_UNIQUE` (`spscId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `htId_idx` (`htId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `atId_idx` (`atId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `lid_idx` (`leagId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `tId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`htId` )
    REFERENCES tams (`tId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `atId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`atId` )
    REFERENCES tams` (`tId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `lId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`leagId` )
    REFERENCES leags (`lid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

If I remove the lId as a FK and the constraint from the above sql, the table creates just fine. I can't figure out where the duplicate key is in here. All help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Formatting fixed. Strangely enough, using the code or block quote wouldn't fix it, had to manually add spaces :(

Comment: I may be wrong, but your index names are duplicated within the database and they need to be unique.

Comment: Are you on windows or MAC?

Comment: @Mihai Why do you insist on calling it "MAC"? That means something [entirely different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lId` you already have a constraint with this name in table tams `lid`.

I suspect your system is not case sensitive.

http://richardfearn.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/case-insensitive-constraint-names-in-mysql/

> internally, InnoDB stores foreign key constraint names as
>   case-insensitive, with the database name prepended. So although
>   onedatabase.b_ibfk_1 is treated as different to
>   anotherdatabase.b_ibfk_1, Photos.b_ibfk_1 and photos.b_ibfk_1 are
>   treated as the same.

Just pick another name for that key.

Comment: That's it! When I changed the constraint to leagId, the table created just fone. Thanks so much.